# Clearing a complex map

Tags: c++

I have a map in C++ as:

```
std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::unique_ptr<T>> my_map;
```

Will using `my_map.clear` cause memory leak issue ?

Comment: Provided that `T` is well-behaved, no it won't.

Comment: Let's see if we can get beneath this. What lead you to worry about a possible leak?